# error: 'wxGraphicsContext' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

`#include <wx/graphics.h>` file included,
wxWidgets 3.0.2 on Windows 7 compiled with `USE_GDIPLUS=1` flag.
and still I get this error

```
error: 'wxGraphicsContext' was not declared in this scope
```

What might be causing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets doesn't use `USE_GDIPLUS` anywhere. If you meant `wxUSE_GRAPHICS_GDIPLUS`, then it is not a make option but a C++ one, i.e. you need to edit your `wx/setup.h` to enable it. If you use MinGW (and not MSVC) you also need to make sure that you have the necessary headers and libraries installed as not all distributions of MinGW include them (but e.g. TDM-GCC does).

Comment: You ment `wxUSE_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT`? should I compile both wxWidgets and my code with TDM-GCC? if so, I get this error while compiling my code `error: 'strnlen' was not declared in this scope` do you know how to fix that?

Comment: `c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`
I get this error when compiling using TDM-GCC `C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc -j4 USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1
 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1`

Comment: I'd recommend creating a separate question about this as it doesn't have anything to do with the original one. Make sure to mention the version of the compiler you use.

Comment: OK, will do, but you did meant `wxUSE_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT` is that correct?

Comment: It's an option in `wx/setup.h`.